# Mulesoft SFTP write .csv file encoded UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: utf-8, sftp, dataweave, byte-order-mark, mule4

I have the requirement to store a csv file with the SFTP write processor from Mulesoft on an SFTP server.

File format: CSV (comma as separator), UTF-8 with BOM

In a "transform message" I transform the JSON payload into application / csv encoding = "UTF-8"

That works great, the csv is then available on the SFTP server in utf-8 format.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv encoding="UTF8" 
---
payload.data
```

My problem is how can I attach the BOM to the file?

Comment: Not sure about Mulesoft (the tag description on Stack Overflow says it's not a single product, so perhaps you should clarify which Mulesoft component exactly?) but adding the BOM before uploading should certainly fox it. The requirement is problematic but if your audience consists of Windows victims, maybe that's the simplest way forward.

Comment: By context I can tell the question is for Mule 4. I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Before you write the data to SFTP create a variable called utf8BOM using the dataweave below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/java 
---
fromHex("EFBBBF")
```

Then create your new file using a write connector and write the variable above first: e.g. in the content put
vars.utf8BOM

Then write your content to the same file using append on the write connector.

This should output a UTF8 CSV file with the BOM bytes.